# Select only groups with subgroups who all have an observation

Tags: r, dplyr

I have following  data (see below). I try to calculate the amount of a type of product (e.g.: apple) bought by one company, in every year. I managed to find code for this part. Next I want to only select companies who bought apples every year and leave the other companies out. So my desired output is to have grouped data first by company, than by type, than by year with the amount of type bought per company per type for year, but only for companies who bought something every year. In this way I only keep long term clients and see their buying pattern. I thought a filter would do the trick, but it also returns companies who are not long term clients. Unfortunately I did not find a  solution when searching for it on the internet.

Many thanks if someone would be able to help!

**Code**

```
MASTERDATA %>%
  group_by(COMPANY,Type,Time)%>% 
  summarize(Amount_COMPANY = (sum(Amount, na.rm=TRUE)))%>%
  filter(Type=="Apple",Amount_COMPANY>0)
```

**Data example**

| Productnr | Type | Amount | COMPANY | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 29 | Company1 | 2003 |
| 1 | Pear | 271 | Company2 | 2004 |
| 3 | Apple | 565 | Company2 | 2001 |
| 2 | Banana | 354 | Company2 | 2006 |
| 2 | Pear | 984 | Company3 | 2003 |
| 1 | Banana | 247 | Company3 | 2000 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show only those companies which bought something (= any product) in every year, then we can `group_by(COMPANY)` and filter those which have `length(unique(Time))` (where `Time` comes from each company)  equal `length(unique(.$Time))` (where `.$Time` comes from the whole data set).

I changed your example data to make it clearer how this works. We are only looking at the years `2001`, `2002` and `2003` and want to filter companies which bought something (any `Product`) in each year.

```r
library(dplyr)

MASTERDATA <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Productnr,    ~Type, ~Amount,   ~COMPANY, ~Time,
  1L,  "Apple",     29L, "Company1", 2003L,
  1L,  "Apple",    271L, "Company2", 2003L,
  2L,  "Apple",    354L, "Company2", 2001L,
  2L,  "Apple",    984L, "Company3", 2003L,
  1L,  "Apple",    247L, "Company3", 2001L,
  1L,  "Pear",     29L, "Company1", 2003L,
  1L,  "Banana",    271L, "Company2", 2003L,
  3L,  "Banana",    565L, "Company2", 2002L,
  2L,  "Pear",    354L, "Company2", 2001L,
  2L,  "Banana",    984L, "Company3", 2003L,
  1L,  "Pear",    247L, "Company3", 2001L
)

MASTERDATA %>%
  group_by(COMPANY) %>% 
  filter(length(unique(Time)) == length(unique(.$Time)),
         Type == "Apple") %>% 
  group_by(COMPANY, Type, Time) %>% 
  summarize(Amount_COMPANY = (sum(Amount, na.rm=TRUE))) 

#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'COMPANY', 'Type'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   COMPANY, Type [1]
#>   COMPANY  Type   Time Amount_COMPANY
#>   <chr>    <chr> <int>          <int>
#> 1 Company2 Apple  2001            354
#> 2 Company2 Apple  2003            271
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! What is the reason you use arrange before?

Comment: Oh, this step was basically for me when playing around with the data to get a better overview. We don’t need it, so I delete it from my answer.

Comment: What if you want to filter for companies that bought only apples in every year?